# In Pokémon Go, why does one of my Pikachu have an option to evolve, but another one doesn't?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why does one of my Pikachu have an evolve option, and the other doesn't? Does this mean that I cannot evolve the other one?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A rather vague question with no images, however given the timing I'll assume it is to do with the recently released Straw Hat Pikachu.  This event Pokemon has been specifically set so that you can't evolve it.

Comment on twitter from Niantic Support

> Q: why can't we evolve pikachu in this event?
>
> A: Hello Trainer! Straw Hat Pikachu is a special event Pokémon and
>   hence cannot be evolved into Raichu. Thank you for your question! Let
>   us know if we can help you with anything else. ^DS

[Niantic Support Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1154022652631310336)

Comment: Odd reasoning considering all the other hatted versions could be evolved into Raichu and also hatched as Pichu.

Comment: I thought they would have done this with detective or the ash hat Pikachu since those make sense to stay as Pikachu

Comment: It's worth noting that many other pikachu with hats (from previous events) cant evolve either. I think Pikachu in that context is just a novelty for a celebration of that event and not intended to have a Raichu of the same event.

Comment: @OnlineUser02094 that's wrong - all the other hat Pikachu can be evolved

Comment: Niantic Support isn't well known for accurate information

Comment: Its a copyright issue, only pikachu is allowed to have one piece straw hat, not raichu, or pichu.

Comment: @andyADD do you have a source?