# If I evolve a Pikachu wearing a Party hat does the Raichu still wear the hat?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been catching Pikachus wear some spiffy looking hats on Pokemon Go. Some of them have party hats, while others have Santa hats. If I decide to evolve them into Raichus, do they get to keep their spiffy hats?

Comment: In addition to the dup, the only exception is [Straw Hat Pikachu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/355834/124566) which cannot evolve

Comment: @Wondercricket Thank you for the insight on the Straw Hat Pikachu